# Android. Вызов Фрагмента из Активити

Tags: android, android-fragment, button, android-on-click

Как можно вызвать фрагмент из MainActivity по нажатию кнопки.

Сам фрагмент.

```
public class EventInterestFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_event_interests, container, false);
    }
}
```

и в что нужно вписать сюда, чтоб вызвать\отобразить фрагмент с XML файлом)

`public void btn_click (View v) { Реализация по вызову фрагмента. }`

И можно пожалуйста реализацию. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит вызвать фрагмент? Просто если это какое-то диалоговое окно, то можно вызвать диалог и в него загрузить свою XML разметку.

Comment: @NikotinN ну у меня есть Фрагмент и в дальнейшем буду дополнять код там и мне нужно, чтоб по нажатию кнопки, вызывался Fragment со всем, что есть внутри.

Comment: В общем, первая ссылка при поиске в Google - http://metanit.com/java/android/18.2.php . как раз то что вам нужно, диалог, который открывается при клике на кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, тупанул что-то. Не правильно искал походу)